# How do preserve leading and trailing whitespace when using an input tag?

Tags: html, angularjs

I am playing with Angular and writing a Regex tester.
Problem is leading whitespace is trimmed when I enter data.  See example [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/MrSteve/T2zuV/11/):

So when the page loads I have the RegEx "^\d+$".test(" 123 ") which results in "No Match", But if you enter an extra leading or trailing space in the Candidate box:

1. The leading and trailing spaces are removed from my variable
2. The result changes "Match"

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id='ng:app' class='ng-app: myApp' ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-controller="Controller">{{addTodo2()}}
        <form novalidate class="simple-form">Pattern:
            <input type="text" ng-model="pattern" />Candidate:
            <input type="text" ng-model="candidate" />
            <br />.{{candidate}}.
            <br>.{{candidate2}}.</form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the associated JavaScript:

```
function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.pattern = "^\\d+$";
    $scope.candidate  = " 123 ";
    $scope.candidate2 = " 123 ";
    $scope.addTodo2 = function () {
        var str = "Javascript is an interesting scripting language";
        var re = new RegExp($scope.pattern, "g");

        var result = re.test($scope.candidate);
        if (result) {
            return "Match22";
        } else {
            return "No Match22";
        };
    };

  }
var myapp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

Comment: have you seen or tried ng-trim="false" in your inputs?

Answer (score 12):

Updated the fiddle, added ng-trim="false" to the input tags

http://jsfiddle.net/T2zuV/12/

```
<div id='ng:app' class='ng-app: myApp' ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-controller="Controller">{{addTodo2()}}
        <form novalidate class="simple-form">Pattern:
            <input type="text" ng-model="pattern" ng-trim="false"/>Candidate:
            <input type="text" ng-model="candidate" ng-trim="false"/>
            <br />.{{candidate}}.
            <br>.{{candidate2}}.</form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Strange thing is ng-trim is NOT in the documentation for 1.1.5 (probably why I didn't see it), but it is in the documentation for 1.1.1.  I did a quick look at the source code for 1.1.5 and it is still there, but it is not in the source code for snapshot.

Comment: @MrSteve sorry don't know what to tell you regarding the docs... I just happened to have seen this directive already and knew it handled the situation you were encountering, I suppose there must be a way to contribute to the docs.

Comment: Okay clarification on the docs.  While you can not find ng-trim at: [link](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input.text) which are the docs for the latest stable release 1.0.7.  Seems ng-trim was introduced in 1.1.1

Comment: @MrSteve alright well that makes more sense I suppose.  From what I understand the docs are generated/built automatically off the comments in the source so you should always have the latest docs so to speak built into the code (not sure what the grunt task is to build the docs, or if it's done some other way, but would be nice to understand the angular build process a bit better, perhaps I'll start exploring).  Thanks for the tips.. if this answered your question please accept the answer (hit the check mark) too so others know this question is answered.  If there's an issue feel free to edit.