# angular ng-model - how to read only space chars from input field

Tags: angularjs, input

I have an input field with ng-model="myCharsInput".
If I type space `(' ')` and then in the controller when I read the myCharsInput, it is an empty string.

There is a way to allow user to type space and I can read it?

thanks

Comment: Add `ng-trim=false` to the element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do preserve leading and trailing whitespace when using an input tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739726/how-do-preserve-leading-and-trailing-whitespace-when-using-an-input-tag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `ng-trim="false"` directive to avoid trimming input

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myCharsInput" ng-trim="false">
```